# Imagick not enough processor power?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to do crop animated gif on VDS with this configuration:

~800MHz and 256 RAM

And it's not working. It just eats memory and processor and after a ~minute returns no responce.

http://i192.photobucket.com/albums/z228/Somebi/no-responce.jpg

http://imm.io/1OID

On local machine i'v created a virtual machine with 256 RAM.
Everything works fine, but a bit slow i must admit...
But i have Duo Core 7400 on local machine.

I have tried to limit memory usage on VDS with these settings:

```
$gif = new Imagick($s['src']);

set_time_limit(0);
$gif->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY,32);
$gif->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP,64);

// echo $gif->getResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY);
// echo $gif->getResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP);
// echo $gif->getResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_FILE);
// echo $gif->getResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK);
// echo $gif->getResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA);
// exit;

$gif = $gif->coalesceImages();

foreach($gif as $frame){
    $frame->cropImage($s['params']['w'], $s['params']['h'], $s['params']['x'], $s['params']['y']);      
    $frame->setImagePage($s['params']['w'], $s['params']['h'], 0, 0);
}   

$gif->writeImages($s['dest_path'] .'/'. $fullname,true);
```

But can i limit processor usage?

And is there any solution for slow VDS? :|

Thanks everyone!

**update:**

```
   print_r(getimagesize($s['src']));
   exit;

   $gif = new Imagick($s['src']);
   etc...

    Array
(
    [0] => 530
    [1] => 150
    [2] => 1
    [3] => width="530" height="150"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/gif
)
```

**update2:**

```
pathinfo($s['src'])

(
    [dirname] => images/tmp
    [basename] => 43138a0723d6ae0799564bd6acb8c7b83c8df483.gif
    [extension] => gif
    [filename] => 43138a0723d6ae0799564bd6acb8c7b83c8df483
)
```

**update3:**
How to debug imagick extension? :(

Have found this package:
http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/testing/13/i386/debug/php-pecl-imagick-debuginfo-3.0.0-5.fc13.i686.html

Have anyone tried it?

Comment: What does `$s['src']` contain?

Comment: When i'm removing limits, i'm getting error header "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error after a minute or more.

Comment: $s['src'] contains uploaded gif

Comment: @Beck what do you mean by uploaded GIF. The raw data, or a file path, or a URL?

Comment: safe_mode Off Off (from phpinfo page)

Comment: Have you tried with a different GIF to make sure it is not some weird format problem?

Comment: Yea trying another gif, with less animation, with 3 images inside! And it worked! So the problem is with VDS resources. What to do then...

Comment: Maybe i should make some pause between gif frames cropping?

Comment: And why does it takes so much time to crop gif with 3 frames?

Answer (score 0):

You could increase php's maximum execution time, i believe it defaults to 60 seconds.

At runtime with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), or ini config with [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

ok, scratch that, i see your already doing it. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to speculate that `$s['src']` contains a remote URL.

That could mean that your real trouble is fetching the remote image. The firewall or something else could be causing the script to time out.

Try it with a local image instead first. I would bet half a beer that it works fine then. In that case, experiment with fetching the remote file using `file_get_contents()` instead. I think I read something somewhere that IMagick's constructor has trouble with URLs.

Comment: @Beck okay, then this is not it! I owe you half a beer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your php script on command line to see whether it has anything to do with execution time.

```
shell> php <your-script-name>
```

You may have to replace full path to `php` if it's not in your `PATH` environment variable.

Keep in mind that ImageMagick is optimized for quality; not for speed. There's a similar library called [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) which (they say) is running well with low resources. You may consider trying it if you still experience resource issue.